# Modern CMake - setup libraries targets inside project

Tags: cmake

My project structure presents as follows:

```
── src
    ├── app
    │   ├── first_app
    │   │   ├── include
    │   │   └── src
    │   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── second_app
    │   │   └── ...
    ├── lib 
    │   ├── first_lib
    │   |   ├── include
    │   |   └── src
    │   |   └── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── second_lib
    │   |   ├── include
    │   |   └── src
    │   |   └── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
```

*first_app* uses both *first_lib* and *second_lib*. I would like to force CMake to find all dependencies (libraries and include headers) using

`target_link_libraries(first_app first_lib::first_lib second_lib::second_lib)`.

I would like to ask two questions:

1. What command should be used to export first_lib::first_lib in *./src/lib/first_lib/CMakeLists.txt*?
2. How to make first_lib::first_lib visible in .*/src/app/first_app/CMakeLists.txt*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you create your lib using `add_library(first_lib ...)`

1) I would use:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS first_lib
  EXPORT FirstLibTargets
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/first_lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
)
```

src: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-cpp/blob/master/Foo/CMakeLists.txt#L24
then you can install the export file using:

```
install(EXPORT FirstLibTargets
 NAMESPACE first_lib::
 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/FirstLib
 COMPONENT Devel)
```

src: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

note: I don't know if you can install target alias (i.e. `install(TARGETS first_lib::first_lib`) and/or have an export file with differents namespace (i.e. `first_lib::` `second_lib::`)

2) simply use in first_lib/CMakeLists.txt:
`add_library(first_lib::first_lib ALIAS first_lib)` just after your add_library.

so first_app could always use `first_lib::first-lib` to retrieve this target dependencies what ever if you use a Meta CMake (i.e. `add_subdirectory()`) or `find_package()`.
e.g. https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-cpp/blob/master/Foo/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you Mizux Dev for your solution. It works exactly as I wanted.